# Avoid unncessary relationship Rest Api Response JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot Application with 10 Tables in my database. When i make a get request on one table,  it returns a response with in all the tables having any related records in all the 10 tables. I use Lazy fetch, the problems does not solve. I need to return only response  expectated by front end app. For example, if the client wants only students then the REST API should return only students (not its child entities). How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a JSON response and get a particular field/fields from Response by customising it.

The other option is to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the fields which you don't want them to be part of response.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating DTOs for your use cases and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Student.class)
public interface StudentDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<CourseDto> getCourses();

    @EntityView(Course.class)
    interface CourseDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`StudentDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, StudentDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<StudentDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!